# How to invoke QML methods from C++?

Tags: qt, qml

I have my QML file which contains methods. These methods need to be called from **C++** by using QMetaObject::invokeMethod().

**QML :**

```
// MyItem.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    function signalBroker(name, value) {
    if (name == "volume_radio") {           
        updateVolume(value);
    } else if (name == "mute_radio") {
        updateMute();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Well, the second sentence of the question answers it.

Comment: Qt documentation does not have many examples , Do you have any example for my case or explanation?

Comment: You mean like this documentation page: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#invoking-qml-methods ?

Comment: Feel free to call invokeMethod() whenever you want.

Comment: As a general recommendation I would say to rethink if you really want this. This creates a C++ -> QML dependency, i.e. C++ relying on certain objects with certain API to exist on the QML side. Integration is usually done the other way around to retain flexibility on the dynamic QML side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you wanna rely on Javascript but here is the complete code.

sample.pro

```
QT += qml quick
QT -= gui
SOURCES += main.cpp
RESOURCES += resources.qrc
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlComponent>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, "qrc:/main.qml");

    QObject *object = component.create();

    QVariant name = "volume_radio";
    QVariant value = 24;
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "signalBroker",
            Q_ARG(QVariant, name),
            Q_ARG(QVariant, value));

    delete object;

    return app.exec();
}
```

resources.qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    function updateVolume(value) {
        console.log('Volume from C++ = ' + value)
    }

    function updateMute() {
        console.log('Radio is now mute.')
    }

    function signalBroker(name, value) {
        if (name === 'volume_radio') {
            updateVolume(value)
        } else if (name === 'mute_radio') {
            updateMute()
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it I get the following output

`qml: Volume from C++ = 24`

**Please Note**: On main.cpp when loading the `main.qml` file please make sure to provide a full path (or `:/main.qml`) or a qrc URL or the compiler will not find the QML file you are trying to load.

Your app can be a GUI app or a console app, it does not matter so long as you include the corresponding header files and update your `.pro` file.

Comment: Thanks Eddie, can i call this every where on my qt class : QObject *object = component.create()  QVariant name = "volume_radio";
    QVariant value = 24; ?

Comment: Yes so long as the `QtCoreApplication` or `QtGuiApplication` is constructed. Why not just create a function or something? Please remember if you are trying to get the returned value of the Javascript function you need to use `Q_RETURN_ARG` instead of `Q_ARG`. For example, `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "javascriptFunc", Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, valueFromJS));` where `valueFromJS` is of type `QVariant` as well.

Comment: @Ismaela.D Im glad it is working now. Please accept the answer as well. You can find the accept button on the top left hand side of the answer and please feel free to ask more questions if you have any. Thank you ;-)